# form.post_bind is fired twice

Tags: php, symfony

I added a form event to my Symfony Form. The problem is that this event seems to be fired twice. When I am debugging, it goes twice into the method and I don't know why.

I have a form Type that uses another form type. I have a VideoFileType form that is adding a field of ImageType. Both of these forms need some process to be done once the form is submitted.

**ImageType**

```
<?php
# src/Acme/PhotoBundle/Form/Type/ThumbnailType.php

namespace OSC\MediaBundle\Form\Type;

use OSC\MediaBundle\Manager\ImageManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ObjectChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    private $imageManager;

    public function __construct(ImageManager $imageManager) {
        $this->imageManager = $imageManager;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', 'file');

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            array($this, 'onPostSetData')
        );
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array('data_class' => 'OSC\MediaBundle\Entity\Image');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'OSC\MediaBundle\Entity\Image'
        ));
    }

    public function onPostSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $image = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        //We need here to update the image file with the new content
        $image = $this->imageManager->uploadImage($image);
        $event->setData($image);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image';
    }
}
```

**VideoFileType**

```
<?php
# src/Acme/PhotoBundle/Form/Type/ThumbnailType.php

namespace OSC\MediaBundle\Form\Type;

use OSC\MediaBundle\Manager\VideoFileManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ObjectChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class VideoFileType extends AbstractType
{

    public $container;

    public $videoPresets = [];

    public $videoFileManager;

    public function __construct(VideoFileManager $videoFileManager, Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $videoPresets = $container->getParameter('osc_media.video.presets');
        foreach ($videoPresets as $key => $videoPreset) {
            array_push($this->videoPresets, $key);
        }

        $this->videoFileManager = $videoFileManager;

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('thumbnail', 'image');
        $builder->add('file', 'file');
        $builder->add('videoPreset', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->videoPresets,
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => true
        ));
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            array($this, 'onPostSetData')
        );
        $builder->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function onPostSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $videoFile = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        //We upload the video file
        $videoFile = $this->videoFileManager->uploadVideoFile($videoFile);

        $event->setData($videoFile);
    }


    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array('data_class' => 'OSC\MediaBundle\Entity\VideoFile');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'video_file';
    }
}
```

I don't know why the `onPostSetData` method is called twice...

Comment: I don't see where the `VideoFileType` is adding a `ImageType`.  However you do have an event listener on each type so if you are calling one with the other the event will trigger both times.  Maybe seeing how you are calling it in your constructor will help.  Can you clarify?

Comment: this line: `$builder->add('thumbnail', 'image');`

Comment: Thats interesting, not sure I recognized you could reference it that way.   However I am pretty sure your problem is the second `$builder->addEventListener(`  You should be able to remove it from image and have it only fire once.

Comment: @BRad When I debug, I can enter the onPostSetData in both forms

Comment: Removing the event in ImageType did not help. It still called the onPostSetData method twice

Comment: Can you minimize the issue and reduce functionality?  Maybe remove image from the video file manager to see how it fires.  Its hard to give suggestions when I am not sure what it is we are trying to achieve other than it not firing twice.

Comment: @CoachNono provide your controller's code please